# cucumber junit runner java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Trying to implement cucumber to do some automated tests. jUnit tests. I've created 2 files and edited pom.xml that comes with maven project to add dependencies. Content is shown below. The first of two files are cucumber .feature files, which is a gherkin of plain language. The other is CukesRunner.java

When I run my tests using `Project -> Run as ... -> Maven test` it works as expected.

However when I ran the CukesRunner.java file using Eclipse the Eclipse JUnit GUI, I get an error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Serializable;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lorg/junit/runner/Description;
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.getDescription(FeatureRunner.java:43)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:77)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:226)
    ...
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.bdd</groupId>
  <artifactId>airportparking</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>airportparking</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rubiconproject.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jchronic</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

CukesRunner.java:

```
package com.bdd.airportparking;

import cucumber.api.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
        format={"pretty", "html:target/cucumber"},
        features="src/test/resources"
        )
public class CukesRunner {

}
```

ValetParking.feature:

```
Feature: Valet Parking
    As a traveler
    In order to determine where to park my car
    I want to know the cost of valet parking

Scenario: Calculate valet parking cost for half an hour
    When I park my car in the Valet Parking Lot for 30 minutes
    Then I will have to pay $12
```

Output when running `CukesRunner.java` as a `Junit Test`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.Description.createSuiteDescription(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Serializable;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Lorg/junit/runner/Description;
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.getDescription(FeatureRunner.java:43)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:77)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.describeChild(Cucumber.java:41)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.getDescription(ParentRunner.java:226)
    at org.junit.runner.Runner.testCount(Runner.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestClassReference.countTestCases(JUnit4TestClassReference.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.countTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**How I structured my project in eclipse:** 
http://postimg.org/image/vf6tlw7el/full/

Comment: Where do you have your `stepdefs`?

Comment: @Bala Where should it be?

Comment: check this answer. It might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753267/cucumber-jvm-undefined-step/21754450#21754450

Comment: I have the same problem so I am bumping. I infer from the stack trace that you are running the test in Eclipse. I am editing the question to reflect my experience, which is that is works if you "Run as... -> Maven test"

Comment: @Onizuka, Did you ever manage to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 22):

Updating your junit version and maybe also your surefire plugin will fix this problem.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

For surefire:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and got fixed once I configured the latest version. The issue was on junit version 4.10. the latest version from 4.11 works good

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Different story but same issue... developing a Jenkins plugin, using gradle, had the latest `junit:junit:4.12` library on my classpath...

The issue was being caused by the `junit:junit-dep:4.10` library, "aka"...

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
    <version>4.10</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

After explicitly removing it from my configuration classpath, I no longer have the issue.

Comment: That's what resolved my issue i.e. getting rid of junit-dep

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have updated my POM as below, and it gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and i found that i have configured both junit 4.10, and 4.11 in my build path, Adhering to junit 11, resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue and is resolved by using the JUnit version to 4.11 or higher. Ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cukes/et3rd_0LVRU

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the correct JUnit version in your POM.xml.
Change it to latest from 4.10 to 4.11 it works.

Answer (score -1):

I have updated my junit driver from 4.9 to 4.11; it is absolutely a junit driver problem, so just update it, and you will get it.

Comment: Why not version 4.12?